# ARM Assembly to find number of substrings

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm trying to write an arm assembly code to find number of substrings of a given string. I have 2 functions, one of them will call another one. Here is the code I wrote so far:

```
.global substr_s
.global matches_s

substr_s:  //Return a pointer to the first location of s2 in s1 if s2 is a substring of s1. If s2 is not a substring of s1, then the function will return 0 (NULL).
   
    mov r4,r0 //store the pointer to string
    mov r5,r1 //store the pointer to substring
    mov r6,#0

    str r4, [sp,#16]
    str r5, [sp,#20]
    str r6, [sp,#24]

loop2:
    ldrb r2,[r0] // load first character of the string
    cmp r2,#0  //if it is 0 exit
    bne match  // otherwise branch to match
    b exit

match:
    ldrb r2,[r4]  //first char of string
    ldrb r3,[r5]  //first char of substring
    cmp r3,#0     // if at the end of substring go to advance
    beq advance
    cmp r2,#0     //if at the end of string exit
    beq exit
    cmp r3,r2    // compare
    beq next     //if equal go to next and increment to next char
    add r0,r0,#1 //if not advance string pointer by one
    mov r4,r0
    mov r5,r1
    b loop2

advance:
   mov r6,r0  //store r0 in r6 and exit
   b exit

next: //increment to next char
   add r4,r4,#1
   add r5,r5,#1
   b match

exit:
   mov r0,r6
   ldr r6, [sp,#24]
   ldr r5, [sp,#20]
   ldr r4, [sp,#16]
   bx lr


// This function below has problem

matches_s:

   sub sp, sp, #32
   str lr, [sp]
  
   ldrb r2,[r0] //get first char of string
   mov r3, #0   //count = 0
  

loop:
   cmp r2, #0  //if char is 0 quit
   beq end
   b substr_s  //otherwise branch to find the substring
   ldrb r2,[r0] //check the returned char
   cmp r2, #0   // if it's 0 quit
   beq end
   add r3, r3, #1  //else increment counter by 1
   add r0, r0, #1  //go to the next char
   ldrb r2,[r0]    //get the char
   b loop          //loop again to find substring starting from new pointer

end:
   mov r0,r3
   ldr lr, [sp]

   bx lr
```

and here is the c code

```
char *substr_c(char *s1, char *s2) {
    char *p1, *p2, *rv;
    rv = 0;

    while (*s1 != '\0') {
        /* Loop over all characters in s1 */
        p1 = s1;
        p2 = s2;
        while (*p1 != '\0' && *p2 != '\0' && (*p1 == *p2)) {
            /* See if s2 is a substring here */
            p1 += 1;
            p2 += 1;            
        }
        if (*p2 == '\0') {
            rv = s1;
            break;
        }
        s1 += 1;
    }

    return rv;
}

int matches_c(char *s1, char *s2) {
    int count = 0;
    char *next;
    
    while (*s1 != '\0') {
        if ((next = substr_c(s1, s2)) != 0) {
            count += 1;
            s1 = next + 1;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

I tested the assembly code and it seems problem is the matches_s function. it does not return the correct value of count. for example here is one output :

```
 ./matches aabb aa
matches_c(aabb, aa) = 1
matches_s(aabb, aa) = -1094981728
```

I guess problem is the registers but i can't find it. any help is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: In `matches_s` you jump to `substr_s` using `b`. That should be `bl` if you want `substr_s` to be able to return to the right location.

Comment: 2nd line of matches_s is `str lr, [sp]`; this is abnormal, but should return properly.  I don't have time to run through this, but the end of *match* looks like `mov r5,r1` might be     `mov r1,r5` to get the 'C' `p1 = s2`.  `s2` never changes in the 'C' code.